# Design for an autosave feature

Tags: website-design, responsive-design

I'm developing a web app that has several text fields that can be edited. I implemented an autosave feature that saves each time there is change in the title field.

I need to let the user know that the title is saved in a subtle way.
Currently I have a small "saving..." / "saved" tag in the top left of the page. This solution is not very good because it overlaps some background images and they are hiding it.

I thought of pointing to the change of a date/time field but I cannot find an eye catching solution that is subtle. Is there a best practice for how to go about this?

Comment: Do you have a mockup you can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have any header/footer bars available in the app? The first thing that came to mind is Google's auto-save notification across their apps, which they display on headers and footers. This is a subtle, yet informative way to display the saving status.

**Google Drive** (header)

[image: Drive's autosave]

**Gmail** (footer)

[image: Gmail's autosave]

Comment: And another note: consider including a manual save button like Google, unlike Microsoft, so that the user can feel more confident.